# Read Access Violation on Virtual Function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

This is a simplified version of my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {

    }

    void virtual update()
    {
        std::cout << "no update function\n";
    }
    void virtual draw()
    {
        std::cout << "no draw function\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
    void draw() override;
    void update() override;
};

Derived::Derived()
{

}

void Derived::draw()
{
    std::cout << "draw";
}

void Derived::update()
{
    std::cout << "update";
}

class Caller
{
public:
    Caller();

    void update();
    void draw();

    void reg_obj(Base* obj);
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> all_objects;
};

Caller::Caller()
{
    Derived derived_class{};
    reg_obj(&derived_class);
}

void Caller::update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < all_objects.size(); i++)
    {
        all_objects[i]->update();
    }
}

void Caller::draw()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < all_objects.size(); i++)
    {
        all_objects[i]->draw();
    }
}

void Caller::reg_obj(Base* obj)
{
    all_objects.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Base>{obj});
}

int main()
{
    Caller caller{};

    while (true)
    {
        caller.update();
        caller.draw();
    }
}
```

This code works, but when it's in my full program between `caller.update();` and `caller.draw();` the __vfptr value in memory does not stay the same.  When approaching `caller.draw()` the __vfptr value changes every step through the debugger.  I'm not sure how to diagnose memory corruption in __vfptr as it's not something I programmed, but part of the C++ standard.  Any help is appreciated. And no, I can't make a reproducible version.  I don't know why.  I did make an effort to make it reproducible.

https://youtu.be/yd-76qDa7xc <- this video shows the problem
https://github.com/Sage-King/Alienor <- source for non-functional code

Comment: From what you show here it appears that the `all_objects` array might be getting corrupted, possibly by an out-of-range write to a neighboring variable.

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is `-1`. An Access Violation near address 0 typically means a NULL pointer is being accessed. Double-check your object pointers are valid. Especially since you claim the vtables are not showing as the same when making the different method calls. Where is your `Alienor` object being created and used from, and how is its `all_objects` being populated? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why the `inline`: `inline static unsigned int ID_Factory = 0;`?  I have never used `inline` with a variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I recreated the problem in another project and it works fine.  Should I put my entire codebase (or a clone link)? I don't know how else to make a minimal example while keeping all of the work I've already done.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It was the only way I could define the variable in a header file.  To be honest, I don't totally understand it myself.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, reading the memory it seems that my virtual function pointers are getting corrupted.  They change every step I make through the program, and point to garbage.  My only confusion is that the all_objects array works for one call, and then the next call (immediately after), does not work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau all_objects is being populated using std::vector.push_back.

Comment: @SageKing "*This code works*" - actually no, it doesn't. `Derived derived_class{}; reg_obj(&derived_class);` is causing **undefined behavior** in the rest of your code. You are storing a pointer to a local object that is destroyed afterwards, leaving a dangling pointer in the `all_objects` vector. All of your method calls on `all_objects` elements are acting on *invalid memory*. To fix that, change `void reg_obj()` to take a `shared_ptr<Base>` and store it as-is, and then change `Caller()` to create the `Derived` object using `std::make_shared()`...

Comment: @SageKing ... like this: `void Caller::reg_obj(std::shared_ptr<Base> obj) { all_objects.push_back(obj); } Caller::Caller() { reg_obj(std::make_shared<Derived>()); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much!!!! It worked.  I can't mark your comment as correct.  Is it worth me trying to create an answer for future stuck devs or should I leave the question as is? Thanks again!

Comment: @SageKing the question is closed, so an answer can't be posted until the question is reopened. I have cast a vote to reopen, but a couple of more votes are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from Remy Lebeau:
`Derived derived_class{}; reg_obj(&derived_class);` is causing undefined behavior in the rest of your code. You are storing a pointer to a local object that is destroyed afterwards, leaving a dangling pointer in the `all_objects` vector. All of your method calls on `all_objects` elements are acting on invalid memory. To fix that, change `void reg_obj()` to take a `shared_ptr<Base>` and store it as-is, and then change `Caller()` to create the `Derived` object using `std::make_shared()`like this: `void Caller::reg_obj(std::shared_ptr<Base> obj) { all_objects.push_back(obj); } Caller::Caller() { reg_obj(std::make_shared<Derived>()); }`